# Why does this Laravel CSRF vulnerability work?

Tags: php, csrf, laravel

Recently [Laravel 4](https://laravel.com/) was updated to address a security concern: [there was a CSRF vulnerability in their code](https://web.archive.org/web/20150310152942/https://blog.laravel.com/csrf-vulnerability-in-laravel-4/).

Here's the old code:

```
if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
{
    throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
}
```

And here's their fix (note the `!==`):

```
if (Session::token() !== Input::get('_token'))
{
    throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
}
```

I understand the difference between `==` and `===` in PHP (basically the latter is more strict because it checks type), and I understand what CSRF is and how to address it, but I don't fully understand why this specific case creates a vulnerability, or how an attacker would exploit it.

Comment: I don't know Laravel that well, but is there any chance that Input::get('_token') can return something that is not a string, like the boolean TRUE? TRUE is == to all strings, for example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

chrismsnz here...

Long story short, DarkLighting is pretty much right.

`Input::get()` usually reads from request parameters, but if the request is JSON then it reads from the JSON body. JSON allows you to specify the type of data so instead of a CSRF token string, I sent an int(0) which will pass that loose comparison most of the time.

The other trick is that usually you cannot send JSON requests cross-site, due to the CORS check in browsers. However, Laravel has a very poor JSON check, it basically checks to see if the string `'/json'` is anywhere in the content type and if its there, runs the whole request through a JSON parser and feeds it into `Input`.

Therefore you can exploit it using something like this (jquery example)

```
$.ajax("http://<laravel app>/sensitiveaction", {
    type: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8; /json',
    data: '{"sensitiveparam": "sensitive", "_token": 0}',
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, for the explanation. One thing that i wanna ask is this: why did int(0) match the session token? You put that as a literal zero or just an example? If that is a literal, shouldn't the server-stored session token value be different than that?

Comment: Yep, this is what the Laravel patch addresses. PHP weak comparisons are pretty broken... try running this code and it should provide some insight: `<?php var_dump('RaNdOmStRiNg' == 0); ?>`

Comment: Ok, now i got it. According to [this link (paragraph right after the table)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), if you compare a string and a number, the string will be converted to a number and the comparison will be numerically made. Man, this is SOOO counterintuitive... Thanks again for taking the time to enlighten us, Chris.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it was a private disclosure, so it seems that we will not know this for sure unless someone takes the time to analyze the framework code (or @chrismsnz decides to explain it to us).

But from what i could tell, it seems like [Session::token()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Session/Store.html#method_token) returns a *string* and [Input::get()](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Input.html#method_get) returns a [*mixed*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php) object.

By the rather *short* explanation they gave, the researcher found a way to make the variable contain arbitrary data using [JSON](http://blog.laravel.com/csrf-vulnerability-in-laravel-4/), but the value did not have the correct type (*string*). As the framework was only checking for the correct value, he was able to bypass the filter.

Comment: No exploit?  How did it work?

Comment: As i said above, it looks like the laravel framework uses private disclosures, as i was unable to find details about the flaw other the stated in their short comment on the subject. Maybe some months from now the researcher will make a public release explaining everything...

Comment: Hi! I'll write this up for you below...